# Explicit Lipschitz continuous bijection from unit cube to unit ball

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

I am looking for a Lipschitz continuous bijection from the (closed or open) unit cube $Q$ to the (closed or open) unit ball $B$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I found a continuous bijection via
$$f(x) = \max_i |x_i | \frac{x}{|x|}.$$
Now I am struggling to prove that it is Lipschitz though (which I'm pretty sure it is). Can anyone help?

Comment: Obtaining an adequate Lipschitz constant for this particular function is surely possible, but hopefuly tedious. I would instead consider that the unit cube and the unit euclidean ball are unit balls (in the general meaning) for $\|\|_1$ and $\|\|_2$ norms resp. Therefore there exists constants $k,k'$ such that  $k \|u-v\|_1\leq\|u-v\|_2 \leq k'\|u-v\|_1$...

Comment: Thank you for your response! I suppose instead of $\| \|_1$ you mean $\| x\|_{max}:=\max_i \mid x_i \mid$? Then indeed the unit cube is the unit ball under this norm. I have already derived the inequalities you stated, namely we have $\| x\|_{max}\le \| x\|_2\le n^{\frac{1}{2}}\| x\|_{max}$. I still don't see how this gives us a Lipschitz continuous bijection though to be honest. What am I not seeing?

Comment: First thing : yes indeed it is the meaning I give to $\|\|_1$. Second thing : you have to consider that there is a "hidden function" when you use such inequalities. In fact for example $\|u-v\|_2 \leq k'\|u-v\|_1$ can be written $\|u-v\|_2 \leq k'\|f(u)-f(v)\|_2$...

Comment: Oh ok (I know $\| \|_1$ as $\sum_i \mid x_i \mid$). Then it makes sense. But when I try to find an $f$ s.t. your inequality holds, I end up with $f_j(u)=u_j$ if $\mid u_j \mid = \max_i \mid u_i \mid$ and $f_j(u)=0$ for all other $j$ ($f_j$ denoting the $j^{th}$ entry of $f$). Then indeed, $f$ is a Lipschitz continuous function from the cube to the ball, but it is not bijective anymore. How can I fix that? Sorry I am still confused.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake ; I meant $\|\|_{\infty}$

Comment: No worries, that's what I thought :) But still, I don't see how that will give me a Lipschitz bijection (as I said above, with your ansatz my function $f$ won't be bijective anymore). How can I go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your map $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is
$$ f(x) = \frac{\|x\|_\infty}{\|x\|_2} x $$
with inverse
$$ f^{-1}(x) = \frac{\|x\|_2}{\|x\|_\infty} x .$$

We first want to show that $f$ is Lipschitz, that is, if $\|x - y\|_\infty \le \epsilon$, then there is a constant $C$, depending only on $n$, such that
$\| f(x) - f(y) \|_2 \le C \epsilon$.

Consider the following cases.

1. $\|x\|_\infty, \|y\|_\infty \le \epsilon $.  Then clearly $\| f(x) - f(y) \|_2 \le \|f(x)\|_2 + \|f(y)\|_2 \le \|x\|_\infty + \|y\|_\infty \le 2\epsilon $.
2. $\|x\|_\infty > \epsilon $.  Then
   \begin{align}
   &\| f(x) - f(y) \|_2
   \\&= \left\| \frac{\|x\|_\infty}{\|x\|_2} x - \frac{\|y\|_\infty}{\|y\|_2} y \right\|_2
   \\ &\le \left\| \frac{\|x\|_\infty}{\|x\|_2} x - \frac{\|x\|_\infty}{\|x\|_2} y \right\|_2 + \left\| \frac{\|x\|_\infty}{\|x\|_2} y - \frac{\|y\|_\infty}{\|y\|_2} y \right\|_2
   \\&\le \frac{\|x\|_\infty}{\|x\|_2} \|x-y\|_2 + \frac{\|x\|_\infty \|y\|_2 - \|x\|_2 \|y\|_\infty}{\|x\|_2\|y\|_2} \|y\|_2
   \\&\le \sqrt n \|x-y\|_\infty + \frac{\|x\|_\infty \|y\|_2 - \|y\|_\infty \|y\|_2 + \|y\|_\infty \|y\|_2 - \|x\|_2 \|y\|_\infty}{\|x\|_2}
   \\&\le \sqrt n \|x-y\|_\infty + \frac{(\|x\|_\infty - \|y\|_\infty) \|y\|_2 + \|y\|_\infty (\|y\|_2 - \|x\|_2) }{\|x\|_2}
   \\&\le \sqrt n \|x-y\|_\infty + \frac{\|x-y\|_\infty \|y\|_2 + \|y\|_\infty \|y-x\|_2 }{\|x\|_2}
   \\&\le \sqrt n \|x-y\|_\infty + 2\sqrt n\frac{\|x-y\|_\infty \|y\|_\infty}{\|x\|_\infty}
   \\&\le \sqrt n \|x-y\|_\infty + 2\sqrt n\frac{\|x-y\|_\infty (\|x\|_\infty+\epsilon)}{\|x\|_\infty}
   \\&\le \sqrt n \|x-y\|_\infty + 4\sqrt n\|x-y\|_\infty
   \end{align}
3. $\|y\|_\infty > \epsilon $.  Argue as in the second case.

This shows $f$ is Lipschitz.  Showing $f^{-1}$ is Lipschitz is similar.

Comment: Thank you a lot! That solves my problem.

Comment: Just a question: $f(0):=0$?

Comment: @FormulaWriter Yes.